# Missing a part from an internally threaded steer tube

Tags: fork, headset

I recently obtained and then disassemble a Kink Co. BMX. It had a threadless headset. Unexpectedly, instead of having a star nut inside the fork's steer tube, the steer tube was internally threaded (threaded on the inside) and something screwed in. I lost that "something" and have no recollection of what it looked like. What am I working with here? I have never seen a fork like this. I obviously need to replace a part, but can't without any names whatsoever.

Comment: Welcome to bicycles.SE! It would help a lot if you posted a photo of the steer tube and noted any brand name or numbers written on it.

Comment: A picture would be nice. You're probably just missing the preload bolt, but we can't tell for sure from the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after one of [these](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/Models.aspx?ModelID=51368).

Does the same job as a top cap and star nut but has a hole you can run the front brake line down.

Comment: And they are called generically as "Pre-Load Bolt"?

Comment: I believe so. Sticking "bmx preload bolt" in Google got a load of results. https://encrypted.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=bmx+preload+bolt

Comment: How much does one differ from another? Do I need to be worried about hunting down the right size? The right brand? The right threading? Etc.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I would assume they're pretty standard as long as you get the right diameter.